# Protect against csrf using go backend and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, go, csrf

I have Vue.js front end which uses a backend json API developed in golang. I want to protect against csrf, I looked at https://github.com/gorilla/csrf and their example. Im not sure how to implement this as it seems that my golang web server needs to serve/render the vue app?

```
let csrfToken = document.getElementsByName("gorilla.csrf.Token")
  [0].value


  const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com/api/",
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: { "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken }
  })


  try {
      let resp = await instance.post(endpoint, formData)

      } catch (err) {
      // Handle the exception
      }
```

Comment: How are your calls authenticated? If you're not relying on cookies for it, no need for CSRF protection. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints

Comment: @ceejayoz- When user logs in I send a session key in the resoonse header. Every new request add that session key to the request header.

Comment: You should be fine, then.

Comment: @ceejayoz- What if I want to use cookies in the future. I would I implement the example I showed